# Implementing UNet model for Multi Class (4-classes) Image Segmentation

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to implement a UNet model, on labeled image data. The dataset contains around 10,000 images and their respective masks (colored-RGB).

Image Dimensions: 500 X 500 X 3

The masks are not black & white, they are colored (RGB), having 3 classes (technically 4):

- Background: Black
- Class 1: Red
- Class 2: Green
- Class 3: Blue

This is the code for the last two CONV blocks of the model:

```
    model = Conv2D(64,(3,3),strides=(1, 1),padding='same')(concat_5)
    model = LeakyReLU(0.1)(model)
    model = BatchNormalization()(model)

    model = Conv2D(4,(3,3),strides=(1, 1),padding='same', activation="softmax")(model)

    model = Model(base_model.input,model)
```

Model Architecture:

```
Model: "functional_1"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            [(None, 500, 500, 3) 0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block1_conv1 (Conv2D)           (None, 500, 500, 64) 1792        input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block1_conv2 (Conv2D)           (None, 500, 500, 64) 36928       block1_conv1[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block1_pool (MaxPooling2D)      (None, 250, 250, 64) 0           block1_conv2[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block2_conv1 (Conv2D)           (None, 250, 250, 128 73856       block1_pool[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block2_conv2 (Conv2D)           (None, 250, 250, 128 147584      block2_conv1[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block2_pool (MaxPooling2D)      (None, 125, 125, 128 0           block2_conv2[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block3_conv1 (Conv2D)           (None, 125, 125, 256 295168      block2_pool[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block3_conv2 (Conv2D)           (None, 125, 125, 256 590080      block3_conv1[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block3_conv3 (Conv2D)           (None, 125, 125, 256 590080      block3_conv2[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block3_pool (MaxPooling2D)      (None, 62, 62, 256)  0           block3_conv3[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block4_conv1 (Conv2D)           (None, 62, 62, 512)  1180160     block3_pool[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block4_conv2 (Conv2D)           (None, 62, 62, 512)  2359808     block4_conv1[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block4_conv3 (Conv2D)           (None, 62, 62, 512)  2359808     block4_conv2[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block4_pool (MaxPooling2D)      (None, 31, 31, 512)  0           block4_conv3[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block5_conv1 (Conv2D)           (None, 31, 31, 512)  2359808     block4_pool[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block5_conv2 (Conv2D)           (None, 31, 31, 512)  2359808     block5_conv1[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block5_conv3 (Conv2D)           (None, 31, 31, 512)  2359808     block5_conv2[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block5_pool (MaxPooling2D)      (None, 15, 15, 512)  0           block5_conv3[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_5 (Conv2DTrans (None, 31, 31, 256)  1179904     block5_pool[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_10 (LeakyReLU)      (None, 31, 31, 256)  0           conv2d_transpose_5[0][0]         
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_10 (BatchNo (None, 31, 31, 256)  1024        leaky_re_lu_10[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_5 (Concatenate)     (None, 31, 31, 768)  0           batch_normalization_10[0][0]     
                                                                 block5_conv3[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_6 (Conv2D)               (None, 31, 31, 512)  3539456     concatenate_5[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_11 (LeakyReLU)      (None, 31, 31, 512)  0           conv2d_6[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_11 (BatchNo (None, 31, 31, 512)  2048        leaky_re_lu_11[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_6 (Conv2DTrans (None, 62, 62, 512)  2359808     batch_normalization_11[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_12 (LeakyReLU)      (None, 62, 62, 512)  0           conv2d_transpose_6[0][0]         
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_12 (BatchNo (None, 62, 62, 512)  2048        leaky_re_lu_12[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_6 (Concatenate)     (None, 62, 62, 1024) 0           batch_normalization_12[0][0]     
                                                                 block4_conv3[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_7 (Conv2D)               (None, 62, 62, 512)  4719104     concatenate_6[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_13 (LeakyReLU)      (None, 62, 62, 512)  0           conv2d_7[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_13 (BatchNo (None, 62, 62, 512)  2048        leaky_re_lu_13[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_7 (Conv2DTrans (None, 125, 125, 512 2359808     batch_normalization_13[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_14 (LeakyReLU)      (None, 125, 125, 512 0           conv2d_transpose_7[0][0]         
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_14 (BatchNo (None, 125, 125, 512 2048        leaky_re_lu_14[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_7 (Concatenate)     (None, 125, 125, 768 0           batch_normalization_14[0][0]     
                                                                 block3_conv3[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_8 (Conv2D)               (None, 125, 125, 256 1769728     concatenate_7[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_15 (LeakyReLU)      (None, 125, 125, 256 0           conv2d_8[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_15 (BatchNo (None, 125, 125, 256 1024        leaky_re_lu_15[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_8 (Conv2DTrans (None, 250, 250, 256 590080      batch_normalization_15[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_16 (LeakyReLU)      (None, 250, 250, 256 0           conv2d_transpose_8[0][0]         
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_16 (BatchNo (None, 250, 250, 256 1024        leaky_re_lu_16[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_8 (Concatenate)     (None, 250, 250, 384 0           batch_normalization_16[0][0]     
                                                                 block2_conv2[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_9 (Conv2D)               (None, 250, 250, 128 442496      concatenate_8[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_17 (LeakyReLU)      (None, 250, 250, 128 0           conv2d_9[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_17 (BatchNo (None, 250, 250, 128 512         leaky_re_lu_17[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_9 (Conv2DTrans (None, 500, 500, 128 147584      batch_normalization_17[0][0]     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_18 (LeakyReLU)      (None, 500, 500, 128 0           conv2d_transpose_9[0][0]         
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_18 (BatchNo (None, 500, 500, 128 512         leaky_re_lu_18[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_9 (Concatenate)     (None, 500, 500, 192 0           batch_normalization_18[0][0]     
                                                                 block1_conv2[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_10 (Conv2D)              (None, 500, 500, 64) 110656      concatenate_9[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_19 (LeakyReLU)      (None, 500, 500, 64) 0           conv2d_10[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_19 (BatchNo (None, 500, 500, 64) 256         leaky_re_lu_19[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv2d_11 (Conv2D)              (None, 500, 500, 4)  2308        batch_normalization_19[0][0]     
==================================================================================================
Total params: 31,948,164
Trainable params: 31,941,892
Non-trainable params: 6,272
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

When I am training the model, I am getting the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentError:  Incompatible shapes: [4,4,500,500] vs. [4,3,500,500]
     [[node categorical_crossentropy/mul (defined at <ipython-input-15-b60b11ed9e76>:9) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_5874]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

It seems that there is some problem with the dimensions of the last CONV layer of the model.
I want suggestions about the following three things:

1. Dimensions of the last CONV layer (considering multi-class segmentation for **4 classes**)
2. Which activation function should I use in the last CONV layer? Currently, I am using `softmax` activation.
3. What kind of loss should I use while compiling the model? Currently, I am using `categorical_crossentropy`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem comes from your classes. What are their formats ? Are they one-hot-encoded ?

Your activation and loss functions are correct for me. I think your last convolutionnal layer should be with a filter of size 1x1 (similarly to the original [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.04597)). It ensures better pixel-classificiation.